# Работа с ConfigurationManager не в текущем контексте. Как?

Tags: .net, ado.net, configuration

Создал решение, в него два проекта: первый - презентация (UI), второй - слой доступа к данным (DAL). В DAL создал файл конфигурации.

Произвожу вызов из UI неких методов находящихся в DAL и использующих файл конфигурации через `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`. И...ничего не происходит, возвращаются nullы. Закрались подозрения, что файл конфигурации ищется, как бы, в текущем контексте (то есть, в моем случае в проекте UI). Скопировал файл конфигурации в проект UI и все заработало.

Возникает вопрос, как быть? Как заставить `ConfigurationManager` искать файл конфигурации в контексте того проекта, в проекте которого находится его непосредственный вызов? Или может какой-то другой подход надо использовать?

Comment: А почему вообще в UI-проекте вам нужны `AppSettings`? Разве это не явно модельная штука? Что-то не так с вашей архитектурой.

Comment: @VladD в UI и не нужен, вызов AppSettings происходит в DAL, что, вроде, логично. Если подробнее, то все происходит примерно так: в UI вызывается, к примеру, метод DAL.GetAllProducts() а уж метод GetAllProducts вызываем AppSettings

Comment: Ну, для начала, не дело UI обращаться к модели. Но это оффтопик по отношению к вашему вопросу. У вас само приложение (exe) почему-то совмещено с UI. Это по идее неправильно. Пусть будет один мини-проект, в котором приложение и конфигурация, UI-проект как библиотека, и DAL как ещё одна библиотека.